# Remove unusable metaboxes in nav menu management screen

Tags: menus, wp-admin, metabox

When you visit `wp-admin/nav-menus.php` and there is no menu you get a set of metaboxes you cannot use. The only thing they do is drawing attention away from the *Create Menu* dialog.

[image]

I want to hide those boxes until there is a menu.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two important global variables in `wp-admin/nav-menus.php`:

- `$nav_menus` is an array of all available menus, filled with [`wp_get_nav_menus()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_nav_menus/).
- `$wp_meta_boxes['nav-menus']` is an array of all available metaboxes for this screen.

We can hook into `admin_head-nav-menus.php`, an action called after the first variable has been set up, and change the second variable:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-nav-menus.php', 't5_hide_dead_menu_metaboxes' );

/**
 * Remove metaboxes for menu items when no menu exists.
 *
 * @wp-hook admin_head-nav-menus.php
 * @return  void
 */
function t5_hide_dead_menu_metaboxes()
{
    empty ( $GLOBALS['nav_menus'] )
        and $GLOBALS['wp_meta_boxes']['nav-menus'] = array ();
}
```

Download as [plugin T5 Hide dead menu metaboxes](https://gist.github.com/thefuxia/4432959) from GitHub.

**Additional Information:**

After removing meta boxes the screen is looking a bit odd. We could change a bit initial hook and add some styles to make it looking better. So our hook could be:

```
/**
 * Remove metaboxes for menu items when no menu exists.
 *
 * @wp-hook admin_head-nav-menus.php
 * @return  void
 */
function t5_hide_dead_menu_metaboxes()
{
    if ( empty( $GLOBALS['nav_menus'] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['wp_meta_boxes']['nav-menus'] = array ();
        echo '<style> #nav-menus-frame { margin-left: 0 !important; padding-top: 20px; } </style>';
    }
}
```

Then the screen will look more natural:

[image]